# Regex replace of special characters in JSON string not working

Tags: javascript, json

I'm stumped...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjjGEE

Why does the regex javascript string replace work for the string with special characters, but not the object converted to a string?

```
let regex = /[\t\r\n]/g

var directString = "{'name':{'first':' billy bob ','last':'\n\rjoe\tblow'}}"
console.log(directString.replace(regex, "a"));

//Output: "{'name':{'first':' billy bob ','last':'aajoeablow'}}"


let obj = {
      name: {
        first: " billy bob  ",
        last: "\n\rjoe\tblow"
      },

    }

let objAsString = JSON.stringify(obj);
let stringifiedString = objAsString.replace(regex, "a")
console.log(stringifiedString)

//Output: "{'name':{'first':' billy bob  ','last':'\n\rjoe\tblow'}}"

//??? Why isn't \n\r and \t being replaced????
```

Comment: You should log the values of `directString` and `objAsString` to the console. You will see that you have two different strings (and I'm not talking about the quotation marks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use escapes like `\n` and `\t` in a string constant (like your first example), what you end up with is a string that contains the intended special characters (newline or tab).

When you JSON encode an object, however, what you end up with is a string that contains the *escape sequences themselves*, not the special characters. The work that `JSON.stringify()` does has to include making sure that a subsequent *parse* of the JSON will re-create the original values of all the string-valued object properties. Thus it turns the embedded special characters in the strings *back* into escape sequences. Your regular expression is looking for the special characters, not the escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Do not attempt to manipulate JSON strings with regexp. Pain will follow.

Instead, do this:

```js
var jsonString = String.raw`{"a": "foo\nbar\rbaz\tqux"}`;

var replaced = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonString, (key, value) =>
      typeof value === 'string' ?  value.replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, '') : value
    ));
                                         
console.log(replaced);
```