# I need to remove the special characters like / using jsonata

Tags: jsonata

Json

```
{ "Data":"i need , to do the transformation / but I am not able " }
```

I need to remove special characters using jsonata

The final output like be
"IneedtodothetransformationbutIamnotable"

Please help me to find solutions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex replace of special characters in JSON string not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732176/regex-replace-of-special-characters-in-json-string-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

[image]

Link to solution in JSONata playground: https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?statev2=eJw1jc0KwjAQhF9lWDxUiNTfS8WbF5%2BhqbBtVy20SUlSEI3vbgp6GmaYb6YsydvJNUKK5Dk68b6zJhmO67hJ%2BoamMwfWVGjqYERaKASL1iI8BMGx8TfrBg4JRI56CriABxgbwHUvaQAfPW9m2gALJ%2Ff0hOKEvLzy6lXlx18%2B9txINr%2Bpf00lWtNSm2XibdzGXdxTpehA1RfxMDne

Code:

```
(
  $regexp := /[^a-zA-Z]/;
  $replace(Data, $regexp, "")
)
```

`$replace` function can take a regular expression as an argument. In this example, `[^a-zA-Z]` is matching anything that's **not** a letter between a-z (lower/uppercase).